# Phonegap - Windows 8.1 , googlemap integration

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

We are facing following issue while integrating google map with phonegap windows build

An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.

The same code is working for Android and IOS platform,

We tried to use Iframe for this, not able to get through this, anybody has any information regarding this, how to solve this issue.

We followed following url to test it.

http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/

The app is working fine when we run it from local machine as the target, When we deploy the same app in windows phone lumia it is not able to include google map api, it shows the "An app can't load remote web content in the local context"

Thanks
Mohsin

Comment: I know ionic does not support windows phone as of now, but if you post some code someone may be able to help.

Comment: I have posted some details to the question,